# How to change the style of buttons which are working with contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

***Hello Stackoverflow World***

```js
$('.bold').on('click', function(){
  $(".commTextarea").focus();
  document.execCommand('bold', null, "");
});
$('.italic').on('click', function(){
  $(".commTextarea").focus();
  document.execCommand('italic', null, ""); 
});
```

```css
.commTextarea{
 background:#EBD9D9;
 border:1px solid red;
 width:350px;
 height:250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="bold" type='button' value='B'>
<input class="italic" type='button' value='I'><br>
<div class='commTextarea' contenteditable></div>
```

**Next js code doesn't work.**

```js
$(document).on('focus', '.commTextarea b', function(){
  $(".bold").css('background','yellow');
});
$(document).on('focusout', '.commTextarea b', function(){
  $(".bold").css('background','white');
});
```

**Alternative code.**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.commTextarea b', function(){
  $(".bold").css('background','yellow');
});
```

Alternative code is working, but how change the style of button when cursor is not in 'bold' ('italic', ...) element.
I hope what I have requested is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply another CSS class to the DOM element, e.g. `.form-input`, so your HTML will look like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-input bold" type='button' value='B'>
<input class="form-input italic" type='button' value='I'><br>
<div class='commTextarea' contenteditable></div>
```

So now it's easy to target all the input elements at once:

```
$(document).on('click', '.commTextarea b', function(){
  $(".form-input").css(...)
});
```

If you prefer you can also use directly the `input` selector, but I wouldn't recommend that, since it will target *all* the inputs in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you very much, there is something to think about, but the question is still relevant.